# I cannot print the array that I am sending to the database - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following function, but when I run it in Postman to see the result, it doesn't print any value to me, it doesn't even give me an error. The `var_dump` set if it detects them, but the array does not... I think there is something wrong in the method `updateOrCreate` , because when I print this variable with `var_dump`, I can't see anything in the console.

This is the function:

```
 public function createBidRival(Request $request)
    {

        $response = array('code' => 400, 'error_msg' => []);
        if (!$request->id_karatekas) array_push($response['error_msg'], 'id_karateka is required');
        if (!$request->id_participant_bid_send  ) array_push($response['error_msg'], 'id_participant_bid_send is required');
        if (!$request->id_participant_bid_receive) array_push($response['error_msg'], ' id_participant_bid_receive is required');
        if (!$request->bid_rival) array_push($response['error_msg'], 'bid rival is required');
        if (!count($response['error_msg']) > 0) {
            try {

                var_dump($request->id_karatekas);
                var_dump($request->id_participant_bid_send);
                var_dump($request->id_participant_bid_receive);
                var_dump($request->bid_rival);

                $bidRival = new BidBetweenRivals();
                $bidRival = BidBetweenRivals::updateOrCreate(
                    [
                        'id_participant_bid_send' => $request->id_participant_bid_send,
                        'id_participant_bid_receive' => $request->id_participant_bid_receive,
                        'id_karatekas' => $request->id_karatekas
                        ],

                    [
                        'id_participant_bid_send' => $request->id_participant_bid_send,
                        'id_participant_bid_receive' => $request->id_participant_bid_receive,
                        'id_karatekas' => $request->id_karatekas,
                        'bid_rival' => $request->bid_rival
                        ]
                );
                  $bidBetweenRivals->save;
                $response = array('code' => 200, 'bidBetweenRivals' => $bidRival, 'msg' => 'Bid created'); 

            }catch(\Exception $exception) {
                $response = array('code' => 500, 'error_msg' => $exception->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dump to see whether `if (!count($response['error_msg']) > 0)` true or not and also dump something in the catch block to see if exception  is occurring or not.

You can also test by commenting out the updateOrCreate part to see if it is interfering.